# Clear text input file

Tags: jquery

I need to delete the text in the input[file] when the uploaded file is larger than 5MB

```
$('input:file').change(
function(e) {
    var files = e.originalEvent.target.files;
    for (var i=0, len=files.length; i<len; i++){
        var n = files[i].name,
            s = files[i].size,
            t = files[i].type;

        if (s > 5242880) {
            alert('Please deselect this file: "' + n + '," it\'s larger than the maximum filesize allowed. Sorry!');
        }
    }
});
```

how can I do?

http://jsfiddle.net/eHNJg/338/

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to do it:

```
$('#fileUpload').live('change',
    function(e) {
        alert('');
        var iSize = ($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0].size / 1024);

         if (iSize/1024 > 5)
         {
             $(this).val("");
         }



    });
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxs76/)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
$('input[type=file]').val("");
```

after `alert()`.

I've reduced the file size limit to for easy testing.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/eHNJg/340/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(this).val("");
```

instead or after the alert